# How to more efficiently generate large amounts of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have a web app running off google apps script, when a user searched for some data I generate templated HTML on the server and return that to the client which populates a table (Each table row is an accordion that expands down for much more detailed info for each item).

The problem is that the HTML generation takes ~20 seconds if the user does a search that returns all data. It returns ~3.5MB of HTML to the client.

I was trying to utilize JQuery templates, but each row may contain different data and that format of that data may change periodically, I had more templates than I did web page. It's not really maintainable to manage a ton of JQuery templates when 15 lines of code (As a "Scriplet") on the server can create the same HTML.

So my question is, how can you serve a large chunk of data to a client and generate HTML without relying on templates for each data format?

If this is not descriptive enough, please let me know.

Comment: apart from time, that's a pretty heavy server load if it takes that long. Use limits and paginate results. Send json instead of html

Comment: It would be interesting to know how long each part of the process takes.  How long is your app waiting to get a return back?  How long from the time the data gets back is until the view is rendered?  There may be developer tools in the browser that can break it down.

Comment: Hey Sandy. I decided to test just that now that you mentioned it, it takes the server 54.8ms on average to generate each row and it's corresponding HTML. Quite a long while actually. I'm looking into making a "general" JQuery template to generate the html from on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the HTML generation takes ~20 seconds

Generate HTML on client side. server only return data .

> if the user does a search that returns all data. It returns ~3.5MB of HTML to the client.

Do not return all data at a time, just return a smallest information. like how many page , category, etc.
  When user select a page , client send a request to get details from server.

Comment: Thanks nill, right now the hard part is how to get the client to generate the HTML. On the server side I can put a for loop into the HTML and generate  HTML dynamically based on the size and contents of an array. I don't think I can do that with a JQuery template.

Comment: @douglasg14b sure you can. Single page apps are in vogue these days  where all the rendering for a complete site of any size is completely done in one  page. One view might be big tables, charts in another view...all without page reload